# Where does this Error in my NestJs Controller Unittesting comes from?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, nestjs

I'm trying to write a test case for my controller, but I just get the same error over and over again. - Already wrote my test case for the service, and its working fine.

In the following I'll provide my code from my: ticket.controller.spec.ts

```
import { TicketController } from './ticket.controller';
import { TicketService } from '../services/ticket.service';
import { CreateTicketDto } from 'src/dto/create-ticket.dto';

describe('TicketService', () => {
  let ticketsControler = TicketController;
  let spyService = TicketService;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const ApiServiceProvider = {
      provide: TicketService,
      useFactory: () => ({
        createTicket: jest.fn(() => []),
        findAll: jest.fn(() => []),
        findByCreator: jest.fn(() => {}),
        findById: jest.fn(() => {}),
        updateTicket: jest.fn(() => []),
        deleteTicket: jest.fn(() => []),
        update: jest.fn(() => []),
      }),
    };

    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [TicketController],
      providers: [TicketService, ApiServiceProvider],
    }).compile();

    ticketsControler = module.get<ticketController>(TicketController);
    spyService = module.get<TicketService>(TicketService);
  });

  it('calling createTicket', () => {
    const dto = new CreateTicketDto();
    expect(TicketController.createTicket(dto)).not.toEqual(null);
  });
});
```

And that's the error im getting all the time =>

line 29 & 30
`Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'TicketController' but required in type 'typeof TicketController'.`

Also I'm getting this error in line 35, but I guess this depends on the earlier problem.  `Property 'createTicket' does not exist on type 'typeof TicketController'.`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some types are not being used properly in your test setup

```js
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [TicketController],
      providers: [TicketService, ApiServiceProvider],
    }).compile();

    ticketsControler = module.get<ticketController>(TicketController);
                               // ^^^^^^ This should be a type. TicketController
    spyService = module.get<TicketService>(TicketService);
  });
```

```js
  it('calling createTicket', () => {
    const dto = new CreateTicketDto();
    expect(TicketController.createTicket(dto)).not.toEqual(null);
         // ^^^ this should be an isntance. ticketController
  });
```

Comment: Alright, was a problem with the types.
For everyone else, in lines 6 and 7 I  did this`let ticketsController = TicketController;` instead of this `let ticketsController: TicketController;`